# python online form (feedback for example) not working

Tags: python, forms, cgi

I'm learning python,, so I got this exercise from a book:
This is an html form:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method=POST action="cgi-bin/cgi101.py">
      <P><b>Enter your name:</b>
      <P><input type="text name=user" />
      <P><input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the script to call:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# parse form data
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
# hdr plus blank line
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
# html reply page
if not 'user' in form:
  print('<h1>Who are you?</h1>')
else:
  print('<h1>Hello <i>%s</i>!</h1>' % cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

by the logic if i enter user it must print

## Hello user

. But it give's

## Who are you?

instead. It means that script doesn't see user in the form. Why?
Cgi/py script is allowed in apache for cgi-bin/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
<input type="text name=user" />
```

This should actually look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="user" />
```

type and name are each attributes on the input HTML tag. The form they will always be in is:

```
<sometag attribute1="a thing" attribute2="another thing" />
```

Please note the position of the quotes and equals signs. A good text editor that does syntax highlighting will help your eyeballs see this more clearly.

Comment: Epic fail... I should not code anymore after catching cold... Thanks!